# numeric representation of the day of the week MySql Vs PHP

Tags: mysql, iso8601, date-format, php

In my PHP code I'm using  date("N") ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday).

Now when I wanted to make a query to search for a specific date.

I found that in MySQL:

- The **date_format** using **%w** will return (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
- The **DAYOFWEEK(date)** will return (1 = Sunday .. 7=Saturday)

Is there a fast way to fix this issue **without doing some PHP** ?

Comment: Using DateTime objects will make your life easier. Much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to match...

```
PHP date('N'):

Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

To one of these...

```
MySQL DATE_FORMAT(col, '%w'):

Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
1   2   3   4   5   6   0

MySQL DAYOFWEEK(col):

Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
2   3   4   5   6   7   1
```

I would use a `CASE` statement with `DATE_FORMAT` as you only have to worry about Sunday.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(col, '%w') = 0
            THEN 7
        ELSE DATE_FORMAT(col, '%w')
   END AS dayofweek
...
```

Comment: Thank you , I Will do it in PHP ... I thought MYSQL had a direct function to do this . I was wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

As is [said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295374/numeric-representation-of-the-day-of-the-week-mysql-vs-php/13295564#comment18129180_13295374):

Subtract or add one (either to PHP or to your MySQL query).

Comment: in php Sunday is 7 and in MySQL Sunday is (0 or 1 depending on the function you are using) so you would need to add test to see if it's 0 or if it's 7 ... as i mentioned in my question no php modifications ... Is there a MySQL function that returns the same as the php method ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (DAYOFWEEK(column)+6)%7 as phpdaten FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, for the current date, you could select the first day of the week as follows:

```
SELECT  DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL
            IF (DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%w') -1  = -1,
                DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%w') + 6,
                DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%w') -1) DAY) FIRST_DAY,
        now();
```

Comment: If you prefer, you can spend a date parameter: SELECT  DATE_SUB('2010-0101', INTERVAL
            IF (DATE_FORMAT('2010-0101', '%w') -1  = -1,
                DATE_FORMAT('2010-0101', '%w') + 6,
                DATE_FORMAT('2010-0101', '%w') -1) DAY) FIRST_DAY,
        '2010-0101';

Answer (score 0):

It surprises me nobody uses mysql `WEEKDAY`. In [ISO -8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) the week starts on monday.

> WEEKDAY(date)
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).
>
> DAYOFWEEK(date)
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 =
>   Saturday).

```
mysql                   PHP                          result
WEEKDAY(date)       ==  date('N' , timestamp) - 1    0: Monday, 1: Tuesday, … 6: Sunday 
WEEKDAY(date)  + 1  ==  date('N' , timestamp)        1: Monday, 2: Tuesday, … 7: Sunday

DAYOFWEEK(date) -1  ==  date('w' , timestamp)        0: Sunday, 1: Monday, … 6: Saturday
DAYOFWEEK(date)     ==  date('w' , timestamp) + 1    1: Sunday, 2: Monday, … 7: Saturday
```

Comment: ISO8601 specifies Monday=1, Tuesday=2 etc. to Sunday=7, so the WEEKDAY() function is not coherent with ISO8601.